# I am trying to make this div move with me when I scroll down but its not working, when I use position: fixed or position: sticky it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this `div` on my home page and want it to move with me when I scroll:
I tried using position:sticky; and position: fixed and adding top: 600px; but its not moving to the top its stuck at the bottom

```css
.linkss {
  color: #8892b0;
  font-family: 'NTR', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 680px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: fixed;
}

.linkss h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #c9c1f5;
}

.linkss a {
  border: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #c9c1f5;
  height: 30px;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div className="linkss">
  <h3>/ Links</h3>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ Etsy Shop </a>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ LinkedIn </a>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/ca/shop/VanillaUnlimited">/ Instagram </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'move with me'. Position fixed fixes the element in the viewport (or other containing block see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) so it stays where it is and the other elements scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML should be "class" instead of "className"

```
<div class="linkss">
```

I tested your CSS after updating the HTML and the menu stayed fixed for me.

Comment: I am using react that's why I am doing className

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you intended with the div. Did you want it to always stay in the same position? Or do you want it to scroll with the rest of the page until it hits a certain point and then becomes fixed?

Comment: I want it to move with me until I get to the end of the page and when I scroll back up I want hit to go up with me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try position sticky.

```
.linkss {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but its stuck at the bottom I did top: 600px; and tried different numbers but its not moving its stuck at the bottom of the page